# How to fill the area between a semicircle and a triangle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) arc (180:0:1cm);
    \draw (0,0) -- (2cm,0) -- (1cm,1cm)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I fill this area?:

[image: Area]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest way is this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=gray] (0,0) arc (180:0:1cm);
    \draw[fill=white] (0,0) -- (2cm,0) -- (1cm,1cm)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you like the borders gray instead of black:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[gray] (0,0) arc (180:0:1cm);
    \draw[gray, fill=white] (0,0) -- (2cm,0) -- (1cm,1cm)-- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the first one. First time I see `filldraw` command. Thanducks!

Comment: @manooooh ducks are welcome! `\filldraw[a-color]` is a shortcut for `\draw[a-color, fill=a-color]`, quack!

Answer (score 9):

A straight-forward way would be just to connect your two paths and make it a `fill` (in case you really want to fill only the two segments):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray] (0,0) arc (180:0:1cm) --
                (0,0) -- (2cm,0) -- (1cm,1cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shorter: `    \fill[gray] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) arc (0:180:1);` +1)

Comment: @Zarko do you like code golfing : `\fill[gray](,)--(2,0)arc(0:180:1);`, shorter ?

Comment: @Kpym, very interesting :-).  i see this first time. where is documented?

Comment: @Zarko that you can delete (0,0) it is obvious because fill do not need a closed curve. That `(,)` is giving `(1,1)` is probably a side effect.

Comment: I sent you some thanks. :-)